# How to access external data inside flash?

Tags: java, web-services, flash, crossdomain.xml

I am new to flash, I have a flash (.swf) file to display my database content through WSDL method. When it is loaded, I can see my data, But it shows some error when it tries to refresh the flash object by itself internally.

I am using eclipse for development, Tomcat 7 as webserver.

And I have placed crossdomain.xml in /Root folder and I am able to display the crossdomain.xml content through web browser by hitting

```
"http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml"

(Note : 1. Both web service and flash file are running in the same server.
        2. This error occurs only before accessing any data from server, once data is accessed the error is not generating anymore)
```

When the flash file tries to refresh itself, It shows the following error.

-->

```
To access external data, add a cross-domain policy file to the external data web server.



For more information, on the Adobe website, see the article "Cross-domain Policy File Specification".



If the problem persists, contact the file creator or your system administrator.


Error: Error #2032

Connection Type: Web Service

File URL: http://localhost:8080/StudentService/performance.swf

External Data URL: http://localhost:8080/StudentService/services/StudentService
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the to-port attribute and the allow-http-request-headers-from element like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Thanks.

@Leo.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, But Am sorry, still I am getting the same error :(.

Comment: Hey I found one more issue, this error occurs only before accessing any data from web service. After accessing any data from web service, the error is not displaying